# Restricting all the views to authenticated users in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I'm working on a project which has a login page as its index and a signup page. The rest of the pages all must be restricted to logged in users and if an unauthenticated user attempts to reach them, he/she must be redirected to the login page.

I see that `@login_required` decorator would make a single view restricted to logged in users but is there a better way to make all the views restricted and only a few available to unauthenticated users?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can write a middleware:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def login_exempt(view):
    view.login_exempt = True
    return view


class LoginRequiredMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        return self.get_response(request)

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        if getattr(view_func, 'login_exempt', False):
            return

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return

        # You probably want to exclude the login/logout views, etc.

        return login_required(view_func)(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)
```

You add the middleware to your `MIDDLEWARES` list and decorate the views you don't want authenticated with `login_exempt`.

Comment: Why using `setattr` here?  Just curious.

Comment: @wim: No real reason. Not using `setattr` is clearer.

Comment: You commented something about excluding some views. Should I do it in place of your comment or just use login_excempt with them?

Comment: @MohammedFarahmand: You can't decorate views that exist in other packages (like the built-in Django login page). You'll have to exclude them manually.

Comment: @Blender How can I exclude the login view manually?

Answer (score 2):

> ...is there a better way to make all the views restricted and only a few available to unauthenticated users?

This is a good use-case for [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/class-based-views/).  Define a base class with the login handling, say `LoginRequiredView`, and make any authenticated endpoints subclass this base, rather than using function-based views with decoration on each function.

The few views available to unauthenticated users will inherit from Django's generic `View` rather than the login required base.

Django actually provides a [mixin class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin) which you can use:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class LoginRequiredView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
```

When a view uses this mixin, or subclasses a base with the mixin, requests by non-authenticated users will be redirected to the login page.

Comment: While I agree on the general advantages of CBVs, this still requires adding the mixin to every affected view (much like the decorator).

Comment: Yep, that is good because its more explicit. Another option would be to define the LoginRequired view and inherit from it instead of view.

Comment: @schwobaseggl  Not necessarily.  You can define a base class with the login handling, and inherit the `LoginRequiredView` instead of Django's generic view.  It's a better approach than decoration, if you find you are using the decorator more often than not.