# Django permissions.IsAuthenticated can check on middleware

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to create global authentication with middleware django restframework which check every request user authenticate or not.

I don't want to add code on every view class like this

@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
class UserProfile(APIView):

Comment: what did you try? if you haven't tried anything then you can start by following this SO question [How to set up custom middleware in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322262/how-to-set-up-custom-middleware-in-django)

Comment: Can you please explain *what* you exactly aim to do, and what you tried and is not working?

Comment: I want to implement  authentication with middleware not add code every view class @permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
class UserProfile(APIView):pass

I want to create global authentication with middleware

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48407790/1324033)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the permissions policy for DRF in your **settings.py** file. Here the [Docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy)

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ]
}
```

Comment: Then you create a middleware for you django app so all routes can required authentication

Comment: @AnilYadav No, You don't need to write in your every view class or function. when you set new permission classes through class attribute or decorators you're telling the view to ignore the default list set over the settings.py file.

Comment: Thanks it working and which url not need authenticate we add 
@permission_classes([AllowAny])